# Does providing PDF content when it could be HTML break accessibility?

Tags: accessibility, section508

I want to provide some very simple content to the user that describes how to use a web form.

This text could just as easily be written in HTML, however, convention among the content writers is to write all help text in Word, convert it to PDF, and then put a link to the PDF at the top of the web application.

Assuming that the PDFs are tagged and/or 508 compliant, does this practice present any accessibility concerns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues posed with your question:

(1) PDF when it *could* be HTML

- This requires the user to have software that reads PDF format.
- This requires the PDF to be tagged and made accessible.
- This interferes with usability and is problematic for some users, especially on mobile where the focus switch to a different (PDF reader) application looses focus on your web page or web browser.

(2) "breaking" accessibility

- The accessibility of your web content is evaluated on its own merits: you certainly can have an accessible PDF but if your reasoning is your HTML does not need to be accessible because of that, you are not accessible and fail your end-users.
- There is also a hidden use-case for accessibility or usability you might not consider: web crawlers and indexing. Users rely on web searching to find content and your PDF is not indexed to map to your web page content in most search engines, so users will not find the help they need.
- Most reasonable people involved with Section 508 would likely agree it is not accessible, as it fails 1194.22(n): *When electronic forms are designed to be completed on-line, the form shall allow people using assistive technology to access the information, field elements, and functionality required for completion and submission of the form, including all directions and cues.*

[§1194.22 Web-based intranet and internet information and applications](http://www.access-board.gov/guidelines-and-standards/communications-and-it/about-the-section-508-standards/section-508-standards#subpart_b)

Comment: I'm accepting this as the answer because the last bullet for both of the issues you extracted does a good job explaining why this is a bad practice. I knew in my gut we were doing something incorrectly, but couldn't formulate why.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to convert Word content to HTML, and you are always highly encouraged to write the content as web content, because there are sometimes issues we simply accessing, and opening PDFs depending on the device they are using.

But to answer your question: no, as long as your PDF is accessible. I'd suggest putting it through something like the accessibility audit tool if you have Adobe Acrobat. If you don't, you might give content creators a simple check list, such as:

- does your image have alt text if needed? (consider a decision tree/flowchart, [example](http://www.4syllables.com.au/2010/12/text-alternatives-decision-tree/))
- are your headings marked properly using the built-in styles?
- are your tables formatted correctly? also tables are not used for layout

You'll probably notice these are typical guidelines when writing web content, but also apply to documents (Word, pdf, etc.).

WCAG has a list of [PDF Techniques](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/pdf.html) that you also want to check, but generally if you make sure that everything is tagged/styled/marked properly in Word, it should save to PDF with the correct tags and such.